# Models not showing in Admin Interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I can not get my models to display within the Admin Interface even after registering them in `django-admin.py` using `admin.site.register(topic)`.

I have registered a model class topic, but it just isn't showing up in the interface. Instead, I'm getting groups and users in the *auth* section and sites in the *sites* section.

Below is the code I currently have. Any help would be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class topic(models.Model): 
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank = True)

class Admin: 
    pass 
    def str__(self):
    return '%s''--' %(self.topic_name)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from edc.kds.models import * 

if __name == "main": 
    management.execute_from_command_line() 
    admin.site.register(topic)
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code snippets from models.py and admin.py.

Comment: models.py...........class topic(models.Model):
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank = True)
    class Admin:
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s''--' %(self.topic_name)
        ...........admin.py..........from django.contrib import admin
from edc.kds.models import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
admin.site.register(topic)

Comment: Next time, edit your question instead of posting the code as a comment. Can you verify that I formatted it correctly? Is that `admin.py` or did you edit `django-admin.py`?

Comment: Have you set the admin site autodiscover on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing some strange stuff.

1: You have some ancient, years old `class Admin` syntax which isn't necessary.

2: You have a strange `if __name` block in there. Clearly that should raise a `NameError`, but assuming you actually wrote `__name__ == 'main'`, there's your problem.

`__name__` is set to `'main'` only if the file is directly executed. If it's executed by django machinery, the if block will never fire, and thus `admin.site.register` will never be called.

Where'd you get this idea?

Comment: Thank u. Iremoved that line as per your suggestion but still the problem is persisting. I'm using django 1.3

Comment: 3 things need to happen. `INSTALLED_APPS` must contain your app. admin.autodiscover() must be called somewhere -- put it in your `ROOT_URLCONF`.  `admin.py` with site registration code must be directly inside of your app. `myapp/admin.py`

Comment: Thanks I found my issue. I observerd that admin.py file is not created in the application folder. Can u tell me why

Comment: "not getting created"? It's not created - you must *put it there yourself*.

Answer (score 0):

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```